# How to create border with different angles in font awesome icons using css?

Tags: css, border, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I want to make a border of font awesome icon exactly like this.
 How to do using css?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDQY3.png)

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: .fa{
font-weight: 700;
font-size:40px;
}
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i><span class="service-icon">Software Development</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i><span class="service-icon">Mobile Apps Development</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i><span class="service-icon">CMS</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span class="service-icon">E-Commerce</span>
   </div>
</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below. Hope this helps.

```css
.icon-container {
  background: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.icon-container::after {
  content: "";
  background: darkgreen;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc( 50% - 0.5rem);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="icon-container">
  <i class="fa fa-car fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: How can i display my text as same line. because while i am using div my text was moving to next line.. Any idea?

Comment: .fa{
font-weight: 700;
font-size:40px;
}
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i><span class="service-icon">Software Development</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i><span class="service-icon">Mobile Apps Development</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i><span class="service-icon">CMS</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span class="service-icon">E-Commerce</span>
   </div>
</div>